# Use Font-awesome in angluar2 webpack

Tags: angular, fonts, webpack, font-awesome

I've been struggling all day to install font-awesome in an angular2 application that uses webpack.

updated my webpack.config.js to include loading font files:

```
 module: {
loaders: [
  { test: /\.ts$/,   loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
  { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
  { test: /\.html/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
  { test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
  // For font-awesome
  {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'}
]
```

},

Installed font-awesome using:

```
npm install font-awesome
```

Added require to ts file 
`require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');`

And I keep on getting this error:

> ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
>   Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3'

Any ideas how to fix this ?.

Comment: There is a plugin [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome), however it has not been updated since 2 months ago and i don't know if it supports newer versions of angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use `style-loader` instead of `to-string-loader`:

```
{ test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'style!css' },
```

Comment: This made the error go away. but I still can't manage to find the icons appearing in the html.

Comment: You need to check your path in file loader `loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'`And also check browser console